# Calling Asp Validator from Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to call a validator to show an error message from JavaScript

For Example:

I have a textbox in which i take time as input and a Button to submit the value.

I have a minimum time and maximum time. 
I'm validating the time textbox using JavaScript and using an alert message to show if there is an error in the time entered

Now instead of showing the alert box I want to call the validation callout extender
to show the error message

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using ASPX validators, these solve javascript and also server side parts.

You can then just ask page.IsValid.

here is some more information about ASPX validator controls

Validators are pretty easy to use, as they support also regular expressions and own functions. But sometimes you've to use two validators on one field. e.g. requiredFieldValidator and Compare validator

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/required-field-validator/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwd43d0x.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx

Comment: Thanx for the info but i need the one i have asked for
because i'm using a time calculator in the pageload and using the javascript to validate the tine entered with the time calculated. So Instead of the alert box i need to call the validator popup message

Comment: you can still use validator controls, together with "ValidationSummary" control, which can nicely present your validation errors, from both, javascript and server side.

Comment: Can you help me in doing that?
How can i use the validation summary

Comment: just put it to the page:
<asp:ValidationSummary />

If you use validator controls, it will work automatically

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.aspx